# Custom login page in grails 2.3.4 with spring security core 2.0-RC2

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I am using the new grails 2.3.4 with Spring Security Core 2.0-RC2 plugin. I have generated the domain objects and got also a user via the `Bootstrap.groovy` into the db. However, I am wondering where to specify a custom login for my page?

Is it also possible to do the sign up process via the spring security plugin?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112918/custom-login-form-in-grails-using-spring-security-plugin

Comment: please tell me what exactly do you want??Is it like you want to login from your custom login page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a gsp in the following pattern: `grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp`.
This way the default template is automatically replaced.